# Wordpress: The specified URL cannot be found - NGINX

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have transfered a Wordpress website from another server/hosting. So I copied all files and the database to make it work on the new server. The website is working well on the front end, all pages are visible en I don't get errors.

But everytime I want to save a page in the Wordpress admin panel, I get the error: "**The specified URL cannot be found**" on the page '**post.php**'. 
I tried to disable the plugins, I tried to add php.ini to the root of the website with the following lines:

```
memory_limit = 64M;
post.max_vars = 5000;
request.max_vars = 5000;
```

But non of these things made it work.

I am working on a **NGINX** server, so it does not use .htaccess (?).

Does anyone got an idea on what I can try to make this work?

PHP info:
    server software: nginx/1.10.2

Comment: go to error logs in your cpanel account, i think you will fiond the problem there

Comment: did you try resetting permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** reason for this problem was the firewall that blocked POSTs from my IP. After editing the firewall and allowing the IP, this problem was solved.